# Kubernetes error when forwarding a port - Connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, tomcat, kubectl, portforwarding, hapi

I'm trying to port-forward my kubernetes service (through minikube) using the following command:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/hapi-fhir-server 8080:8080 --address=0.0.0.0
```

But after trying to reach `localhost:8080` I get the following error: `"....... an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 8080: error forwarding port 8080 to pod {PodID, uid ....:E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8080, 16): Connection refused"`

I checked which port the pod is listening to through the following command
`kubectl get pod hapi-fhir-server-666b846cbf-lhmr4 --template="{{(index (index .spec.containers 0).ports 0).containerPort}}"` resulting in answer `8080`

For if this helps, my service & deployment files (having removed unrelated lines)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ....
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    ....
  template:
      ....
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: .........
          name: hapi-fhir-server
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  ....
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32069
  selector:
    app: hapi-fhir-server
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The image being used is a HAPI FHIR server with the following configuration that runs on Apache Tomcat (server.xml):

```
<Connector port="${server.port}" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               maxThreads="${server.tomcat.max-threads}"
               minSpareThreads="${server.tomcat.min-spare-threads}" />
```

`server.port` being 8080.

I can't seem to find an accurate answer to why this is happening, even after going through documentation or similar questions like: [Kubernetes Port Forwarding - Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799600/kubernetes-port-forwarding-connection-refused).

Is there something I am missing, not doing correctly or that I am not thinking of?
**Note:** I am relatively new to Kubernetes.

Comment: is 8080 maybe already open on your machine?

Comment: @IvanAracki I had already checked this before my question through the command `netstat -a`. I couldn't find a port already being used on 8080. 

I did however check what the error msg would be if the port were to be already in use: `Unable to listen on port 8080: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.]`

Comment: Are you sure that your Dockerfile is using your preferred port?

Comment: Well that was literally the issue, I had not exposed the port in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there was no issue with the Kubernetes or server configuration but rather the Dockerfile that didn't expose port 8080, now it does through the following:

```
# Dockerfile
......
EXPOSE 8080
......
```

Thanks to IvanAracki that pointed this out to me through the comments.